# How can I get all of the purchased products?

Tags: magento, product

This is my code :

```
<?php 
    $_orders = $this->getOrders();
    foreach ($_orders as $_order){ 
        var_dump($_order->getStatus());
    } 
?>
```

this returns me something like this:

```
string(7) "pending" string(10) "processing" string(7) "pending" string(7) "pending" string(7) "pending" string(10) "processing" string(10) "processing" string(7) "pending" string(7) "pending" string(8) "complete"
```

But I want to get all of the "complete" items. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Try `$order->getState()`

```
$_orders = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection();
// to get all the completed order you could do 
//$_orders->addFieldToFilter('state', Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_COMPLETE);

foreach ($_orders as $_order){
        var_dump($order->getState());
        var_dump($_order->getData()); // return all field in sale_flat_order table
        //$_order->getStatus() = $_order->getData('status') - return only the status field
}
```